# After I play games on my laptop, my screen goes black around windows for a few seconds once until I play again

Tags: laptop, drivers, graphics-card, display, nvidia-graphics-card

**My laptop is HP Pavillon Laptop 15-cs2096TX with one integrated graphics card, Intel UHD 620, and one Nvidia graphics card, Nvidia GeForce MX250.**

The problem started on January 2022, when I updated Apex Legends and played it on windowed mode and after a few minutes,  the screen surrounding the game turned black except the taskbar. But the next day when I played Apex Legends again and stopped playing, after a few hours, the screen  first looked like [this](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/650749772394921995/944953066623484015/Screenshot_2022-02-20_190300.jpg) and then something like [this](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/650749772394921995/944953066254401586/cutcut.jpg) for a few seconds(I wasn't able to take a picture when it turned black). This happens only once after playing any game that uses the Nvidia GPU.

I didn't play games for about a month and was doing work like studying using google chrome and nothing happened. I then decided to play Overcooked at night and the next day I opened my laptop, it happened again.

Problems I've faced before with Nvidia GPU:

1. Screen flicker and BSOD

It was on December 2020, I updated my Nvidia driver and after a few days, my laptop started to flicker blue, black, pink, green, etc. and had to force shutdown because I couldn't do anything else. I turned it on and nothing happened but after a few weeks, it happened again and I uninstalled everything, looked for the newest drivers and after a few weeks, it happened again. From January to February, the issue persisted even when I didn't play anything and even got a BSOD until I got a response from my friend and the Nvidia forum that I posted my issue in— the forum said to not install any drivers beyond 460 version and my friend said to install the version 456.38. And so I did and I stuck with that since then.

2. Nvidia bandwidth hungry issue

After every reinstallation of drivers, the nvcontainer.exe would keep using up 7mbps of my bandwidth for a long time and I had to end task the process every time and even reboot, even after disabling automatic updates. It stops after I update the GeForce Experience app and it would use up my bandwidth for a little while but it would only uses a bit of my bandwidth every boot after that.

Comment: @mashuptwice when did i mention about killing my pc during a driver update? And btw, Nvidia always asks me first if i want to install the downloaded update and never updates on its own in the background

Comment: "updated my Nvidia driver ... and had to force shutdown because I couldn't do anything else"

Comment: @mashuptwice I'm gonna edit my post. I meant that i updated and after a few days it started to flicker and i had to force shut down

Comment: Use `rapr.exe` to remove conflicting drivers?  Even if you have the nVidia driver installed, it's still possible due to various factors such as driver conflict, UEFI bad setting, etc., that your system is switching to onboard graphics or your GPU is crashing, which is what the black flashes are indicative of,  Check your `dxdiag.exe` for anything that looks to be out of place, and also check to see if the game you're running supports running on other graphics modes, e.g., DX9.  Oh and see if the problem is present when you install the GPU drivers hosted by your hardware's OEM support page.

Comment: @arctiic I'll try to these solutions. It'll be something that I'll have to  monitor for many days